# Protocols and delegate trouble in swift

Tags: ios, swift

All,

I have create a swift file and put a protocol in it, like this :

```
protocol PayButtonProtocol {
    func enablePayButton()
    func disablePayButton()
}
```

I have made my viewcontroller conform to the protocol like this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PayButtonProtocol
```

I have also created the functions in the ViewController so it conforms like this

```
func enablePayButton() {
        println("Button enabled")
        PAYBarButton.enabled = true
    }

    func disablePayButton() {
        PAYBarButton.enabled = false
    }
```

And in another class, I have set the delegate and I want to execute the enablePayButton when something is pressed like this :

```
 var delegate:PayButtonProtocol?
```

and in the function i want to execute one of the functions by :

```
delegate?.enablePayButton()
```

but it doesn't execute, what am I missing please ?

Comment: have you assigned a value to delegate?

Comment: I have set the delegate as PayButtonProtocol (which is the name of the protocol in the file.

Comment: Defining the delegate variable to be of type PathButtonProtocol is not the same thing as assigning it a value. If you never assign it a value, it will be nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely delegate is nil. Add a breakpoint and check the value of delegate before that line executes. Or change the "?" to a "!" and it will crash if delegate is nil, letting you know what's wrong.

Your code in the other class:

```
var delegate:PayButtonProtocol?
```

defines a variable named delegate that is of type `PayButtonProtocol?`.

The variable `delegate` will contain nil until you assign something to it:

```
delegate = <someObjectThatConformsToPayButtonProtocol>
```

Comment: Yes the delegate is nil.. Why would that be ?

Comment: Presumably because you never set it? Edit your question to show the code that sets the delegate.

Comment: Defining the delegate variable to be of type PathButtonProtocol is not the same thing as assigning it a value. If you never assign it a value, it will be nil.

Comment: I have also done this so that the delegate confirm to the protocol - delegate!.enablePayButton()

Comment: delegate is nil. It will be nil until you assign an object to it. Telling the compiler what type the delegate variable can contain does not create an object to serve as your delegate, or save that object into your delegate property. You must use an assignment statement (`self.delegate=value`) to save something to your delegate property.

Comment: i got it thanks and the println works in the function, but when I try and amend the object it cannot do it and it turns into an optional. I think that means that it has recreated the view controller.

Comment: self.delegate = ViewController()
delegate!.enablePayButton()